# Trigger a build on applying a tag

Tags: git, teamcity, git-tag

I want to achieve the following:

1. Anyone in the dev team creates a tag i.e. Demo_Build_1 to dev branch.
2. TeamCity should be able to detect this new tag and build only this tag.

I have enabled "treat tag as a branch" checkbox in VCS configuration.

I have tried configuring it but I am not able to get it working. Following is my VCS setting:
[image]
and following is how I have configured my build trigger:
[image]

I don't want to trigger a build manually. My idea is that TeamCity should be able to pick up this new tag and run the build. Any pointers to achieve this objective would be helpful.

Comment: Tried replacing `+:Demo*` with `+:refs/tags/Demo*`?

Answer (score 12):

You've got it nearly right. You can use configuration parameter `teamcity.vcsTrigger.runBuildInNewEmptyBranch=true` to tell TeamCity to build on tag creation -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43606.  Otherwise TeamCity won't trigger a build when you see a new tag.

Comment: Doesn't that cause a new build to run for every new branch pushed?

Comment: @BigMoney, yes, it can, but then you can use branch filters in your triggers to restrict the branches you wish to run against.

Comment: This doesn't seem right? Does runBuildInNewEmptyBranch mean new branches *and new tags*?

Comment: @StormMuller, yes, AFAICT

Answer (score 5):

Since I haven't found any complete answer I thought I'd spare someone a couple of hours of hit-and-miss work. I didn't manage to ONLY build tags by editing branch specifications.
Using a branch specification in the VCS trigger as well as in the VCS root leads to no builds. Adding a  -:refs/heads/dev branch specification will still build commits in the branch. As a workaround one could create an unused branch, and specify that as the default branch. That way, since noone commits to that branch, no regular commits will be build, and tags will always be built.

1. Create a second VCS root that only monitors tags
2. In the branch specification of the second VCS root remove the default branch you don't want to build on regular commits and 
   add refs/tags/*
3. Add a VCS trigger without a branch filter
4. This is what the trigger settings should look like
5. Add the magic configuration parameter

This is how my setup looks like: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not particularly useful with all the image links broken.

Comment: I see the images just fine

Comment: Probably blocked by filtering software. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

My configuration is very similar, but yet slightly different, to the @jsaddwater's one:

**Version Control Settings > Branch Filter:**

```
+:*
-:<default>
```

**Version Control Settings > VCS Root:**

- Default branch: master
- Branch specification:

```
+:refs/tags/*
-:<default>
```

- ☑ Enable to use tags in the branch specification

**Triggers > VCS Trigger:**

- Branch filter: (*leave empty*)

**Parameters**:

Add or set Configuration Parameter: `teamcity.vcsTrigger.runBuildInNewEmptyBranch` with the value = true.

---

Tested and working on TeamCity 2019.1.5.

Comment: How can I prevent trigger to run on any new change to branch and only run build on new tag creation only?